# If $\partial_2 f\equiv 0$ on domain, then $f$ is independent of that variable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, smooth-functions

> Let $z=f(x,y)$ be a function of class $C^1(G;\mathbb{R})$.
>
> a) If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\equiv 0$ in $G$, can one
> assert that $f$ is independent of $y$ in $G$?
>
> b) Under what condition on the domain $G$ does the preceding question
> have an affirmative answer?

Sorry if this question has been asked many times but my question is a bit different and it is about part b). But I did not find my question in existing topics.

**Part a)** The answer is NO because one can consider the following function $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$, where $G=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 1<x^2+y^2<4,\ x>0\}$ and
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }(x,y)\in G, x\in [1,2), \\
(x-1)^2, & \text{if }(x,y)\in G,\ x\in (0,1),\ y>0, \\
-(x-1)^2, & \text{if }(x,y)\in G,\ x\in (0,1),\ y<0.
\end{cases}$$
It is easy to see that $f$ depends on $y$ since $f(\frac{1}{2},1)\neq f(\frac{1}{2},-1)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\equiv 0$ on $G$.

**Part b)** I can prove that if $G$ is convex open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then the answer to part a) is YES. But I believe that it is true for larger family of sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$. More precisely, if $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open nonempty set with connected first projections then the answer to part a) is still YES. Here by connected first projections I mean that if $x\in \pi_1(G)$, then for any $y_1, y_2$ such that $z_1:=(x,y_1)\in G$ and $z_2:=(x,y_2)\in G$ the line segment $[z_1,z_2]:=\{(x,\theta y_1+(1-\theta)y_2):\theta\in [0,1]\}\subset G$. This is a larger class of sets since every convex set has this property.

The proof is relatively easy. Indeed, let $x_0\in \pi_1(G)$, then $\exists y_0: (x_0,y_0)\in G$. Let $y$ be such that $(x_0,y)\in G$ and WLOG $y_0<y$. Consider a function $\varphi:[y_0,y]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $t\mapsto f(x_0,t)$. One can check that $\varphi$ is continuous and differentiable on $[y_0,y]$ and by MVT, we have: $\varphi(y)-\varphi(y_0)=\varphi'(c)(y-y_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,c)(y-y_0)=0.$ Therefore, $\varphi(y)=\varphi(y_0)$ which is equivalent to $f(x_0,y)=f(x_0,y_0)$. We have shown that for any $(x,y)\in G$, we have $f(x,y)=f(x,F(x))$, where $F:\pi_1(G)\to \mathbb{R}$ which is defined as: $x_0\mapsto y_0$, where $(x_0,y_0)\in G$. For example, this function $F$ can be constructed by Axiom of Choice. We are done since we have shown that $f(x,y)$ is independent of $y$.

So far I do not see any mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Concerning notation I think the wording "connected first projections" may be confusing. It sounds as if the sets $\pi_1(M)$ are connected for certain $M \subset G$, but you mean that all $G_x = L_x \cap G$ are convex, where $L_x = \{x\} \times \mathbb R$ is the vertical line through $(x,0)$. So perhaps it perhaps would be better to say that the projection $\pi_1 : G \to \mathbb R $ has connected fibers $\pi_1^{-1}(x) = G_x$.

Actually you have shown that each $f \in C^1(G;\mathbb R)$ is constant on each connected fiber $\pi_1^{-1}(x)$.

Perhaps one can also omit introducing the function $F$; doesn't it suffice to say that $f$ being independent of $y$ in $G$ means that all $f \mid_{\pi_1^{-1}(x)}$ are constant?

Let us prove a generalization of your result.

Let $D = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid \pi_1^{-1}(x) \text{ is disconnected}\}$. Note that $D \subset \pi_1(G)$ because $\pi_1^{-1}(x) = \emptyset$ (which is connected) for all $x \notin \pi_1(G)$.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a domain such that $D$ does not have an interior point. Then each $f \in C^1(G;\mathbb R)$ with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \equiv 0$ on $G$ is independent of $y$.

*Proof.* We have to show that if $\xi \in D$, then $f$ is constant on $\pi_1^{-1}(\xi)$. Since $\pi_1(G)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and $D$ does not have an interior point, we find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\pi_1(G) \setminus D$ which converges to $\xi$. Let $y_1 y_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $(\xi,y_i) \in G$. Since $G$ is open, we find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon) \times \{y_i\} \subset G$ for $i =1,2$. We have $x_n \in (\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon)$ for $n \ge n_0$ and may therefore assume w.l.o.g. that all $x_n \in (\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon)$. Hence
$$f(\xi,y_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n,y_i). $$
But $f(x_n,y_1) = f(x_n,y_2)$ since the fibers $\pi_1^{-1}(x_n)$ are connected, hence $f(\xi,y_1) = f(\xi,y_2)$.

We can also generalize your counterexample.

**Theorem.** Assume that there exists a closed interval $[a,b]$ with $a < b$ such that

1. $G_{a,b} = G \cap \left( [a,b] \times \mathbb R \right)$ has the form $G_{a,b} = G_1 \cup G_2$ with disjoint $G_i$ which are relatively open in $G_{a,b}$.
2. There exist $x_0 \in (a,b)$ and $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $(x_0,y_i)  \in G_i$.

Then there exists $f \in C^1(G;\mathbb R)$ with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \equiv 0$ on $G$ which is not independent of $y$.

*Proof.* Choose a differentiable function $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\phi(a) = \phi(b) = 0$, $\phi'(a) = \phi'(b) = 0$ and $\phi(x_0) = 1$. Then
$$f : G \cap\left( [a,b] \times \mathbb R \right) \to \mathbb R,f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}\phi(x) & (x,y) \in G_1 \\ -\phi(x) & (x,y) \in G_2 \\ \phantom{-\phi(}0 & (x,y) \in G \setminus \left( (a,b) \times \mathbb R \right) \end{cases}$$
is a well-defined differentiable function with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \equiv 0$ on $G$, but $f(x_0,y_1) > 0$ and $f(x_0,y_2) < 0$.

*Remark.*

If $f$ is indepedent of $y$, we can define
$$\bar f : \pi_1(G) \to \mathbb R, \bar f (x) = f(x,y) \text{ with any } y \in \pi^{-1}(x) .$$
Note that $\pi_1(G)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and that $\psi = \bar f$ is the unique function such that $f = \psi \circ \pi_1$.

There is no need to work with a "selection function" $F : \pi_1(G) \to \mathbb R$ having the property $(x,F(x)) \in G$ for all $x \in \pi_1(G)$. Such functions always exist by the Axiom of Choice, but in general there is no continuous selection function (let alone an $F \in  C^1(\pi_1(G),\mathbb R)$). But *locally* we can of course take constant selection functions. In fact, for each $(x_0,y_0) \in G$  there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \times \{y_0\} \subset G$. Then clearly $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \subset \pi_1(G)$ and $F : (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \to G, F(x) = (x,y_0)$, is well-defined.

Using such a constant local selection, the chain rule shows that $\bar f$ is $C^1$ on $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$.

Therefore $\bar f \in C^1(\pi_1(G),\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a really good answer! I'll accept it!

Comment: May I ask you few questions about this answer please? So we know that if $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$, where $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open and convex set, $f\in C^1(G;\mathbb{R})$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\equiv 0$ on $G$, then $f$ is independent on $y$. Right? What does this independence mean? Does it follows that that $f(x,y)=h(x)$ for some function $h$?

Comment: @ZFR Convexity implies connected fibers. So $f$ is independent on $y$. This means indeed $f(x,y) = h(x)$. Here $h$ is defined on $\pi_1(G)$.

Comment: Indeed, it makes sense but the fact that $f(x,y)=h(x)$ is bothering me since $f$ has a domain $G$ and $h$ has a domain $\pi_1(G)$. Usually when we say that two functions are equal we require that their domains are identical. Did you get my point?

Comment: @ZFR Yes, $f$ and $h$ have different domains (this **must** be the case for functions with a different number of variables). More formally the equation means that there exists a (unique) $h : \pi_1(G) \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y) = h(\pi_1(x,y))$ for all $(x,y) \in G$. Since $\pi_1(x,y) = x$, this can be written as $f(x,y) = h(x)$ for all $(x,y) \in G$.

Comment: Sorry but I am very confused: 1) But the function $h\circ \pi_1$ has two variables, right? because its domain is $G$. 2) I have never seen the definition of equal function with different domains. 3) why do we care that there is a unique such $h$?  I'd very thankful if you can explain these questions please. I am struggling to understand this even though this is a basic fact I guess.

Comment: @ZFR 1) Yes. The function $h \circ \pi_1$ (with domain $G \subset \mathbb R^2$) must not be confused with $h$ (with domain $\pi_1(G) \subset \mathbb R$). 2) Such a definition does of course not exist. We have $f = h \circ \pi_1$, where both functions have the same domain $G$. Nevertheless it is true that $f(x,y) = h(x)$ for all $(x,y) \in G$. This equation does not claim that $f = h$ as functions (which is impossible), but it says that the *real numbers* $f(x,y)$ and $h(x)$ are equal for all $(x,y) \in G$. Note that LHS and RHS of the equation are well-defined.

Comment: 3) Whether we find it important or unimportant: There is only one function $h$ satisfying theh equation. If $f(x,y) = h_1(x) = h_2(x)$ for all $(x,.y) \in G$, then trivially $h_2(x) = h_2(x)$ for all $x \in \pi_1(G)$. Thus $h_1 = h_2$ as functions.

Comment: I think that I started to understand what you meant! Now the only question is why this $h\in C^1(\pi(G);\mathbb{R})$. The proof which you provided in the answer(the last three paragraphs) is not so clear. Somehow you mixed it with the function $F(x)$ which makes a bit confusing. Can you explain this again please?

Comment: After some deep thoughts I guess this is what you did: so our goal is to show that $\bar{f}\in C^1(\pi_1(G);\mathbb{R})$. One can show that $\bar{f}=f\circ F$ on $\pi_1(G)$.  We already given that $f\in C^1(G)$ and we see $F\in C^1(\pi_1(G))$ (because its partial derivatives are $0$ and $1$, i.e. exists and are continuous). So by chain Rule $\bar{f}$ is smooth on $\pi_1(G)$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @ZFR It makes sense. We want to show that $\bar f$ is $C^1$. Note that $\bar f$ was denoted by $h$ in the previous comments. For each $x_0 \in \pi_1(G)$ we  choose $y_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $(x_0,y_0) \in G$. Note that $y_0$ need not be unique. Then we choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \times \{y_0\} \subset G$ and define $F: (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \to G, F(x) = (x, y_0)$. This map is $C^1$. Hence $f \circ F : (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$.

Comment: But $\bar f \mid_{(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)} = f \circ F$, thus $\bar f$ is $C^1$ around $x_0$. Since this is true for all $x_0$, $\bar f$ is $C^1$.